# json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given?

Tags: php, arrays, json

this is my data ,After `Json_encode()`

```
 Array
        (
            [{"customerId":"1","customer_name":"Jon_doe","amount":"12312312","billcode":"b1231","billname":"cashbilname","billcategorycode":"1234","billcategory":"utility","month":"May","year":"2015","txcode":"10","stationid":"152","station":"Coroom","operatorcode":"1200","operator":"jame","terminal":"ter12312","txdate":"12\/2\/2015","txtime":"12:21:22_PM"}] 
    => 
        )
```

now i want to decode it back ,by applying `json_decode()` it gives the following error

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

any idea sugestion what to do ?

Comment: How do you encode? It looks like you doing something wrong there.

Comment: Can you please post your relevant code?

Comment: You need to pass the first item of that array to json_decode; rather than the whole array. So, `json_decode($array[0])`

Comment: The error message is your answer.Did you searched at google with that error message?You would get lots of result.

Comment: `json_encode` should give you a string in the first place, not the Array you showed, so there's definitely a problem there. Show your code and we might be able to help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `json` must be in `string`, not in `array`

```
$json_string = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$json_array = json_decode($json_string);

$json_array : ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5];
```

---

If your `json` is in `array` you can do :

```
$json_string_in_array = ['{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}'];
$json_array = json_decode($json_string_in_array[0]);
```

Comment: say undefined 0 index

Answer (score 3):

json_encode() returns a string, so I don't know how you can be getting an array out of it unless you are storing it in an array yourself like:

```
$json = [];
$json[] = json_encode($someArray);
```

Instead, just store it in a non-array variable:

```
$jsonString = json_encode($someArray);
```

Then you can decode it like this:

```
$decodedArray = json_decode($jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsonstr = '[{"customerId":"1","customer_name":"Jon_doe","amount":"12312312","billcode":"b1231","billname":"cashbilname","billcategorycode":"1234","billcategory":"utility","month":"May","year":"2015","txcode":"10","stationid":"152","station":"Coroom","operatorcode":"1200","operator":"jame","terminal":"ter12312","txdate":"12\/2\/2015","txtime":"12:21:22_PM"}]';
$ar = json_decode($jsonstr,true); # json string to Array
$obj = json_decode($jsonstr); # json string to Object
var_dump($ar,$obj);
```