# how to decode json object in laravel which is passed as form_data in postman

Tags: laravel, postman, json-deserialization, jsondecoder

In first image you can see how I am sending a json object as form data in `order_details` parameter

[image]

In second image I am getting a response while decoding it in Laravel 7

[image]

```php
public function makeOrder(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'table_id' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'time_slot' => 'required|string',
        'product_ids' => 'required|array',
        'total_bill' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->messages()->first(), 'code' => 404], 404);
    }

    return response()->json(['order' => json_decode($request->order_details), 'code' => 200], 200);
}
```

I am getting the error while decoding the json data.

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: You have declared order_details as an array[]. You would be able to verify the data structure if you try `dd($request->input('order_details')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json\_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050227/json-decode-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order details in the request body is an array, access first index and return it in the response

```php
return response()->json([
    'order' => json_decode($request->order_details[0]),
    'code' => 200,
], 200);
```

This in turn gives this structure in postman, which I assume is what you want

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` decodes a `JSON` string, you probably meant to use `json_encode` instead:

```
return response()->json(['order' => json_encode($request->order_details), 'code' => 200], 200);
```

Comment: Theorically he don't even need json_encode, response()->json does the fact.